# how to find the strings values in a comparision using ollydbg

Tags: windows, ollydbg, debugging, strings

In OllyDbg 1.10 (assembler level deubugger) I can find all referenced text strings

The program compare if a user input string is equal  a internal string.

When I debug the program, I can't find the internal string. I found only the string of the image

The program is a Windows Console (DOS).

This is the string the plugin found

[image: string found with OllyDbg]

This strings appear in the program, but I can't see the string when program say "Congratulations....", is 4 lines under the red mark in the image

You can help?
How I can debug and see the text of comparision?

[image: The program say congrats after compare]

Is like...

if user_input == X then
 print "Congratulations...."
else
 print "Better luck next time..."

How find X string?

Thanks

[EDIT]

After the answer, I recommend, in this case, to use x64dbg

[image: xdbg screenshot with the same information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer by looking at the low-res image but it looks like that the 'X' is not present in as as string in one place. Instead there are bunch of char comparisons spread across this binary.

Like this one:

```
CMP BYTE PTR SS:[ESP+25], 40
```

Gather those together (there should be some above the part that you've pased) and sort by the index (ESP+**xx**). Converting the values after the comma (in this case 40) to ascii and printing them should give you the 'X'.

For the image we have:

> hac__h___rad_$E

Comment: Thanks, this is more visible (for me) in x32dbg, is more easy to read. Many thanks